# Why is this wrong

Tags: delphi, devexpress, variant, tcxgrid

I have the following code

```
procedure TfrmJsApplications.colMaintStylesGetContentStyle(
  Sender: TcxCustomGridTableView; ARecord: TcxCustomGridRecord;
  AItem: TcxCustomGridTableItem; out AStyle: TcxStyle);
var
  aColumn: TcxCustomGridTableItem;
  aValue: Variant;
begin
  inherited;
  try
    aColumn := Sender.FindItemByName('colApplication_Doc');
    aValue := aRecord.Values[aColumn.Index];
    if VarToStr(aValue) <> '' then
      colMaint.Properties.Buttons[0].Caption := 'Redigere'
    else
      colMaint.Properties.Buttons[0].Caption := 'Opret'
  except
    on E:exception do
      Logfile.Error('F_JsApplications.colMaintStylesGetContentStyle: ' + E.Message);
  end;
```

running on a column in a cxGrid.
But for some reason that I simply can't figure out the line

```
if VarToStr(aValue) <> '' then
```

makes the function crash.
I know that it is when aValue becomes a Null value but as far as I can figure out the VarToStr should return '' in this case

Comment: "makes the function crash" doesn't help much. Please provide full error messages.

Comment: It actually doesn't give any message - it just stops the program and displays the source of a Eurekalog unit called ELowLevel in procedure DebugBreak

Comment: @OZ8HP This is still critical information which we need to know in order to be of any help to you.

Comment: I would love to give a message but there is none.
And now the question is closed being too localized.  I don't get it. I will try somewhere else then.

Comment: But what I want to do is to set the caption of a button in a column based on the value of another column - if the column contains data the button should have one text and if not then it should have another text

Answer (score 6):

The `aValue` is probably not `NULL` but `empty`. Try to use check like

```
if(FindVarData(aValue)^.VType in [varNull, varEmpty])then ...
```

instead. Or

```
if VarIsEmpty(aValue) or VarIsNull(aValue) then
```

Comment: Actually    
    if VarToStr(aValue) = '' then
works OK - it looks like it is the 
    colMaint.Properties.Buttons[0].Caption := 'Opret'
that crashes the app